# Need an algorithm to "evenly" iterate over all possible combinations of a set of values

Tags: algorithm

sorry for the horrible title, I am really struggling to find the right words for what I am looking for.
I think what I want to do is actually quite simple, but I still can't really wrap my head around creating algorithms. I bet I could have easily found a solution on the web if I wasn't lacking basic knowledge of algorithm terminology.

Let's assume I want to iterate over all combinations of an array of five integers, where each integer is a number between zero and nine. Naturally, I could just increment from 0 to 99999. [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2], ... [9, 9, 9, 9, 9].

However, I need to "evenly" (don't really know how to call it) increment the individual elements. Ideally, the sequence of arrays that is produced by the algorithm should look something like this:

```
[0,0,0,0,0] [1,0,0,0,0] [0,1,0,0,0] [0,0,1,0,0] 
[0,0,0,1,0] [0,0,0,0,1] [1,1,0,0,0] [1,0,1,0,0] 
[1,0,0,1,0] [1,0,0,0,1] [1,1,0,1,0] [1,1,0,0,1]
[1,1,1,0,0] [1,1,1,1,0] [1,1,1,0,1] [1,1,1,1,1] 
[2,0,0,0,0] [2,1,0,0,0] [2,0,1,0,0] [2,0,0,1,0] 
[2,0,0,0,1] [2,1,1,0,0] [2,1,0,1,0] .....
```

I probably made a few mistake in the sequence above, but maybe you can guess what I am trying to approach. Don't introduce a number higher than 1 unless every possible combination of 0s and 1s has been determined, don't introduce a number higher than 2 unless every possible combination of 0s, 1s and 2s has been determined, and so on..

I would really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction! Thanks a lot

Comment: Why this specific patter? It appears to me that a more natural patter in `[0,0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0,1][0,0,0,1,0][0,0,0,1,1]...`

Comment: Do you actually have to _generate_ the combinations in that order, or could you collect all combinations in a list and sort them in that particular order afterwards? The latter might be significantly simpler, but not always feasible.

Comment: @dawg
I use those sequences as indices in arrays which are sorted „probabilistically“. In this case, I want to break a substitution cipher within the scope of an exercise in a book about cryptography. Basically, for each letter in the ciphertext, I have established an array containing all letters of the alphabet, sorted by how likely it is that they are the correct substitution for the letter in the ciphertext. As the arrays are sorted by probability, [0,0,1,0,0] is More likely to be correct than [0,0,0,1,1], that‘s why I want to test that first.

Comment: @tobias_k 
I don‘t have to generate them, but I want to learn how to generate them.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the sequence would be after [2,1,1,1,1], and after [0,2,0,0,0], and after [2,2,2,2,1]. Could you not give a complete series for arrays with just 3 places, and with digits going up to, and including 2 (instead of 9)? That gives 27 possibilities. What order would they have?

Comment: @trincot
It is not clear to me either, as I don't know how an algorithm generating those sequences would work. For my case, it does not really matter if [0,1,0,0,0] or [0,0,0,0,1] is generated first. The only thing that matters is, that [2,0,0,0,0] is not generated before all possible combinations of 1 and 0 have been exhausted.

Comment: Then it remains unclear. Please consider clarifying, like I suggested with the smaller sized case.

Comment: What you are asking us to do, and what you are trying to understand are different.  In particular, you probably want to look at `[3, 0, 0, ..., 0]` ahead of `[2, 2, 2, ..., 2]`.  Do you want a solution to the general problem or the one you asked?  (Related, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.)

Comment: What is wrong with your approach is that overall letter frequency tells you a lot about the most common letters, and almost nothing about the rest.  So you will have a tremendous number of nonsense permutations of the bottom letters to consider before you can correct, say, a mistake in the 7th most common letter.  But once you've guessed the first 3 letters, you gain a tremendous amount of information about what the rest might be.  So you have to mix evaluation and guessing.

Comment: Concrete example.  Your first try will be that the most common letter is `e`.  The next two most common letters are 't' and 'a'.  But 'et' occurs about 10x as often as 'te', and 'ea' is common in English while 'ae' is extremely rare. This gives you a very good guess as to which of the 5 most common are probably 'a' and 't'.  And your guesses for those 3 fill in about 30% of the message.  At which point you've gained a tremendous amount of information about the rest of the message.

Comment: @btilly
Thanks for your help, I will study your comments tomorrow (its late where I live) and then give you a comprehensive answer :)

Comment: @btilly
Yeah, now that I did it my (the wrong) way, it is obvious that it would make more sense to focus on testing substitutions for the most frequent letters first. However, in this particular exercise that I am working on, I don't have a piece of clear text to compare the decipher-attempt to, and I am just trying substitutions until at least 50% of the deciphered text consists of english words. This is a certainly a "simple" approach and it would make more sense to evaluate more and guess less. But in this case, it is just a textbook exercise, so I am just gonna call it a day for now.

Comment: @MaxLuchterhand Sounds good. This is doable by hand, very doable with a mix of programming and human guessing, and somewhat complicated to automate.  Of course, once automated, it will run very easily.  And you don't need the clear text - just knowing the language is generally enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already said that you can get the combinations you are looking for by enumerating all *n*<sup>*k*</sup> possible sequences, except that you don't get them in the desired order.

You could generate the sequences in the right order if you used an odometer-style enumerator. At first, all digits must be 0 or 1. When the odometer would wrap (after 1111...), you increment the set of the digits to [0, 1, 2]. Reset the sequence to 2000... and keep iterating, but only emit sequences that have at least one 2 in them, because you've already generated all sequences of 0's and 1's. Repeat until after wrapping you go beyond the maximum threshold.

Filtering out the duplicates that don't have the current top digit in them can be done by keeping track of the count of top numbers.

Here's an implementation in C with hard-enumed limits:

```
enum {
    SIZE = 3,
    TOP = 4
};

typedef struct Generator Generator;

struct Generator {
    unsigned top;           // current threshold
    unsigned val[SIZE];     // sequence array
    unsigned tops;          // count of "top" values
};



/*
 *      "raw" generator backend which produces all sequences
 *      and keeps track of how many top numbers there are
 */
int gen_next_raw(Generator *gen)
{
    int i = 0;
    
    do {
        if (gen->val[i] == gen->top) gen->tops--;
        gen->val[i]++;
        if (gen->val[i] == gen->top) gen->tops++;
        
        if (gen->val[i] <= gen->top) return 1;

        gen->val[i++] = 0;
    } while (i < SIZE);
   
    return 0;
}

/*
 *      actual generator, which filters out duplicates
 *      and increases the threshold if needed
 */
int gen_next(Generator *gen)
{
    while (gen_next_raw(gen)) {
        if (gen->tops) return 1;
    }
        
    gen->top++;
    
    if (gen->top > TOP) return 0;
    
    memset(gen->val, 0, sizeof(gen->val));
    gen->val[0] = gen->top;
    gen->tops = 1;    
    
    return 1;
}
```

The `gen_next_raw` function is the base implementation of the odometer with the addition of keeping a count of current top digits. The `gen_next` function uses it as backend. It filters out the duplicates and increases the threshold as needed. (All that can probably be done more efficiently.)

Generate the sequence with:

```
Generator gen = {0};

while (gen_next(&gen)) {
    if (is_good(gen.val)) {
        puts("Bingo!");
        break;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Nice, I also had something like this in mind at first. This will still generate `(0,1,1)` before `(1,0,0)` though (I did not try that exact code, but had the same in Python myself), but that might be okay.

Comment: Thanks. I've ignored all the longish clarifications in the comments and I've used "don't introduce a number higher than 1 unless every possible combination of 0s and 1s has been determined" as specification. There's probably room for improvement.

Comment: Thank you, this looks very promising. I will wrap my head around it and try it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

You could break this down into two subproblems:

- get all combinations with replacement of 0, 1, 2, ... for the given number of digits
- get all (unique) permutations of those combinations

Your desired ordering is still different than the order those are typically generated in (e.g. `(0,1,1)` before `(0,0,2)`, and `(0,0,1)` before `(1,0,0)`), but you can just collect all the combinations and all the permutations individually and sort them, at least requiring much less memory than for generating, collecting and sorting *all* those combinations.

Example in Python, using implementations of those functions from the `itertools` library; `key=lambda c: c[::-1]` sorts the lists in-order, but reversing the order of the individual elements to get your desired order:

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, permutations

places = 3
max_digit = 3

all_combs = list(combinations_with_replacement(range(0, max_digit+1), r=places))
for comb in sorted(all_combs, key=lambda c: c[::-1]):
    all_perms = set(permutations(comb))
    for perm in sorted(all_perms, key=lambda c: c[::-1]):
        print(perm)
```

And some selected output (64 elements in total)

```py
(0, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 0)
...
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 1)
(2, 0, 0)
(0, 2, 0)
...
(0, 1, 2)
(2, 1, 1)
...
(2, 2, 2)
(3, 0, 0)
(0, 3, 0)
...
(2, 3, 3)
(3, 3, 3)
```

---

For 27 places with values up to 27 that would still be too many combinations-with-replacement to generate and sort, so this part should be replaced with a custom algorithm.

- keep track of how often each digit appears; start with all zeros
- find the smallest digit that has a non-zero count, increment the count of the digit *after* that, and redistribute the remaining smaller counts back to the smallest digit (i.e. zero)

In Python:

```py
def generate_combinations(places, max_digit):
    # initially [places, 0, 0, ..., 0]
    counts = [places] + [0] * max_digit
    yield [i for i, c in enumerate(counts) for _ in range(c)]
    while True:
        # find lowest digit with a smaller digit with non-zero count
        k = next(i for i, c in enumerate(counts) if c > 0) + 1
        if k == max_digit + 1:
            break
        # add one more to that digit, and reset all below to start
        counts[k] += 1
        counts[0] = places - sum(counts[k:])
        for i in range(1, k):
            counts[i] = 0
        yield [i for i, c in enumerate(counts) for _ in range(c)]
```

For the second part, we can still use a standard `permutations` generator, although for 27! that would be too many to collect in a set, but if you expect the result in the first few hundred combinations, you might just keep track of already seen permutations and skip those, and hope that you find the result before that set grows too large...

```py
from itertools import permutations

for comb in generate_combinations(places=3, max_digit=3):
    for p in set(permutations(comb)):
        print(p)
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems that in this approach, we firstly generate ALL combinations of elements possible. My array of elements is 27 in length, and each element can be one of 27 different characters. I believe that would leave me with a list of 973469712824060 combinations, of which I would subsequently have to determine all permutations. This doesn't seem feasible. Especially because in my case, I am searching for a certain combination/permutation, which will MOST LIKELY be found in the first 100-200.

Comment: Well, you do not generate all combinations, but "only" the combinations of digits in the number. But yes, for 27 places with 27 possible elements each, that's still way too many. But still, the separation into subproblems should help. It should be easier to adapt an existing combinations-with-replacements algorithm to yield your desired order.